# Toolbar not being shown in child activity

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-toolbar

I am working on having a single navigation drawer for all the activities, so I thought to add it in BaseActivity and then inherit it in other activities wherever I need the navigation drawer and I did indeed succeed in getting the navigation drawer working but for some reason the toolbar is not being displayed in the child activities that inherit the BaseActivity, The I tried a lot things and checkout lot of questions on stack overflow but I could not really figure out what is the issue.

Here is the code: layout file

> activity_base.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am using this layout file here in onCreate of **BaseActivity**:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);         mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

    mAdapter = new NavigationFragmentAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
            // open I am not going to put anything here)
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
        }



    }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

}
```

Then I am inheriting this activity in other child activity (**HomeActivity**):

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_home, content, true);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

The xml file for HomeActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="app.packman.activity.HomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />
<!-- other content of activity-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the output screenshot of HomeActivity which has no toolbar (which is the problem I am facing):
[image]

Any suggestions will of great help

Answer (score 0):

You can try add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in your FrameLayout